# Outlook emails download using Python from other accounts

Tags: python, outlook

I have 2 accounts in outlook. I want to download all mails from the 2nd account (not my primary account) from the Inbox.

I have written a code which is able to download all the inbox mails from my primary account. This code is running fine and storing all the mails into a local folder email_folder The code is as follows:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import re
os.chdir("D:\\email_folder")

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(1)
messages = inbox.items
for message in messages:
    message = messages.GetNext()
    name = str(message.subject)
    name = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', name)+'.msg'    
    message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name)
```

But the problem is when I am trying to get the emails downloaded from the 2nd account then it's not working. I have checked that secondary account number is 3 and the Inbox - sub folder is 13.

I have used the following function to find it.

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = namespace.Folders.Item(3)
def menu(outlookFolderItem):
    for i in range(0,20):
        try:
            print(i,outlookFolderItem.Folders(i).Name)
        except:
            pass

# example
menu(root_folder)
```

Now I want to download the emails from the secondary account from the inbox. I have written the following code which is not working. The code is as follows:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os
import re
os.chdir("D:\\email_folder")

from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
sub_folder = outlook.Folders(3).Folders(13)
messages = sub_folder.items
for message in messages:
    message = messages.GetNext()
    name = str(message.subject)   
    message.SaveAs(os.getcwd()+'//'+name)
```

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never hardcode the folder indices. If you want a default folder (such as the Inbox) from another store, open that store first (using the `Namespace.Stores` collection), then use `Store.GetDefaultFolder` instead of `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. Could you please help me with one last thing; I want to add the iteration number in the name of the mails while saving it (presently the names are same). It should read like customer info 1, customer info 2 like this. I was trying to use enumerate function, but couldn't get it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a different question. Please post it separately and mark this one as answered if the answer worked for you.